# How to fetch object of values in an array from payload using Dataweave 2.0

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I am trying to transform an XML input payload into JSON format. Can someone help me with Dataweave?
[image]
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please provide your input payload as text? Thanks

Comment: Also, what error are you getting? If you have a DataWeave expression, please share it. Thanks

Comment: Is the expression you are using `%dw 2.0 output application/json --- payload`? That should be working, if not please post the errors you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to output?

**Input**

```
<root>
    <entry>
        <ID>ABS</ID>
        <DEPARTMENT>EDF</DEPARTMENT>
        <NUMBER>1234</NUMBER>
        <YEAR>2021</YEAR>
        <POSITION1>12</POSITION1>
        <POSITION2>13</POSITION2>
    </entry>
    <entry>
        <ID>ABFG</ID>
        <DEPARTMENT>123ER</DEPARTMENT>
        <NUMBER>4544</NUMBER>
        <YEAR>2022</YEAR>
        <POSITION1>20</POSITION1>
    </entry>
</root>
```

**Script**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json

fun returnPosition(pkey,position) = {
    b:(payload.root.*entry[position] - "ID" - "DEPARTMENT" - "NUMBER" - "YEAR")
}
---
root:{
    entry: flatten(payload.root.*entry map (entryValue,entryIndex) -> {
    a: flatten(1 to sizeOf((entryValue) - "ID" - "DEPARTMENT" - "NUMBER" - "YEAR" ) map {
                "ID": entryValue.ID,
                "DEPT": entryValue.DEPARTMENT,
                "NUMBER": entryValue.NUMBER,
                "YEAR": entryValue.YEAR ++ returnPosition("POSITION"++($$+1),(entryIndex)).b[($$)]

                

    })
}.a)
}
```

**Output**

```
{
  "root": {
    "entry": [
      {
        "ID": "ABS",
        "DEPT": "EDF",
        "NUMBER": "1234",
        "YEAR": "202112"
      },
      {
        "ID": "ABS",
        "DEPT": "EDF",
        "NUMBER": "1234",
        "YEAR": "202113"
      },
      {
        "ID": "ABFG",
        "DEPT": "123ER",
        "NUMBER": "4544",
        "YEAR": "202220"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Salim. It working as expected. :)